# Count the number of combinations of a pair if the deck is a pinochle deck.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, card-games

the problem goes like this,

A pinochle deck consists of 48 cards. There are six denominations (or values) of the cards: 9, 10, Jack (J), Queen (Q), King (K) and Ace (A). There are two of each denomination for each of the standard suits, ♣,♦,♥,♠. So there are two 9 of ♠s, two Ace of ♣s, etc. A “pair” of cards is two cards with the same denomination. Examples include 9♦ 9♣, Q♠ Q♣ and K♣K♣. A pair is “clean” if the two suits are diﬀerent. Similarly, a “trip” (triple) is three cards of the same denomination, and a “clean trip” has all three of the cards with diﬀerent suits. There are also “quads” (four cards), “quints” (ﬁve cards) and “hexs” (6 cards of the same denomination). You are dealt 6 cards. For each of the following, indicate how many ways that hand can be dealt. Leave your answers as a combinatorial expression, and explain how you got your answers. Like poker, a hand has a “pair” when it has exactly two cards of the same denomination, no other cards of that denomination, and no other cards forming a pair or a larger group. Unlike poker, straights, ﬂushes, etc. do not count for anything.

***I'm currently working on this question and will edit continuously with all my answers, i only want feedback on questions I've attempted so far, thank you.***

1. Exactly one pair. Examples include{9♠,9♣,J♣,Q♦,K♥,A♥}and{9♠,9♠,10♦,J♠,K♥,A♣}.
2. Exactly one clean pair. The ﬁrst example above is clean, the second isn’t.
3. Exactly one pair and one quad.
4. Exactly one clean pair and one clean quad.
5. Exactly one hex.
6. Exactly one clean hex.
7. Exactly one pair and one clean pair. The pairs can not be the same, that would be a quad.
8. Exactly one pair and one clean trip. The pair and trip can not be the same, that would be a quint.
9. Nothing. No pairs, no trips, etc.

**Here are my Answers**

1) I got C(6/1)*C(8/2)*C(5/4)*8^4

2) C(6/1) *C(4/1)*C(3/1)* C(5/4)*8^4

3)  C(6/1) *C(8/2) * C(5/1) * C(8/4)

4)

5)

6)

7)

8)

9)

Comment: Should you be distinguishing between the two copies of each card? You are counting $9_1♠,9_1♣,J_1♣,Q_1♦,K_1♥,A_1♥$ and $9_2♠,9_2♣,J_2♣,Q_2♦,K_2♥,A_2♥$ separately, as though they were different hands.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, for the first question i am distinguishing the two suits, thus the 8 and 7.

Comment: You are counting the two 9♠ as different cards. This may or may not be desirable. Also, using $8*7$ counts everything twice: once as 9♠9♣, then again as 9♣9♠. Using $\binom82$ avoids this double counting, though this still counts 9♠9♣ four times, as there are two choices for each. If this is desirable, then $\binom 6 1 \times \binom 8 2 \times \binom 5 4 \times 8^4$ is correct.

Comment: I see what you mean. i think we don't want the duplicate suits. However i think that C( 4/2 ) is more appropriate because there are four distinct suits. Why doesn't 4 * 3 take into account the duplicate counting? is it because 4 * 3 double counts the different positions? If so, why? I can't seem to intuitively see it because i feel like the problem is solved when i decrement the next multiple operation by 1, because its being taken out

Answer (score 0):

For 3, we:

Choose the value for the quad, then the pair $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}=30$.

Choosing two cards out of 8, there are $\binom{8}{2}=28$ possibilities, and 4 of them are un-clean pairs, so we have 24.

To have a clean quad, we just need to choose one from each suit four times, so $2^4=16.$

Multiplying these together, we have 11520.

For 4, exactly one hex, we have:

Choose one value: $\binom{6}{1}=6$.

Choose 6 cards out of the 8 of the value: $\binom{8}{6}=28$.

Multiplying the two, we have 168.

For 5, it is impossible to have 6 of the same value cards of different suits, because there are only 4 suits, so 0.

For 6 and 7, I'm not sure if you mean one non-clean pair and one clean pair, or one any pair and one clean pair, so I won't answer now.

For 8, we just choose one from each value, as otherwise, we would have at least a pair. Thus, we have $8^6=262144$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @freehaircuts in which step?

Comment: wait sorry, disregard that comment, i talked about the wrong question. For question 3, i think a quad is considered a unclean or clean quad. so shouldn't it just be C (5/1) * C(8/4)?  I say this because in the problem where it gives examples of a pair, the examples include a unclean and clean pair, so the suits can be different or the same so it encompasses all possibilities.

Comment: sorry, i need to edit my post, its very confusing. There's supposed to be 9 questions not 3., it's now edited.

Answer (score 0):

I got for 2) (6C1) * (8C1) * (6C1) * (5C4) * (8C1)^4. For the (8C1) * (6C1), you begin with choosing 1 suit from a possible 8. By definition of clean, you want a different suit, so you can pick 1 more suit from a possible 6 that are left available. So you multiply (6C1). The rest of the expression I got the same.

Comment: Please format your answer using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This makes it easier for everyone to read the answer you have written.